# Multiplication of float number and parseFloat returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get 0.6 of my current count and then show Math.float for it. But NaN is returned

```
$('.unemployed.count').html((Math.floor(parseFloat('0.6')*parseFloat($($('.unemployed.count').text())))).toString(10));
```

Html looks like this

```
   <div id='population'>
        <table id='population_data'>
            <tr tooltip='Unemployed  citizens'>
                <td>Unemployed</td>
                <td class='unemployed count'>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr tooltip='Employed  citizens'>
                <td>Employed</td>
                <td class='employed count'>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.unemployed.count').html((Math.floor(parseFloat('0.6')*parseFloat(
$('.unemployed.count').text()))) // problem is in this line
.toString(10));
```

Instead of

```
$('.unemployed.count').html((Math.floor(parseFloat('0.6')*parseFloat(
$($('.unemployed.count').text()))))
.toString(10));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/L35t5mss/)**

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this

```
parseFloat($($('.unemployed.count').text()))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5v4pfxmk/